# How to execute trigger on delete or update on specific column happen in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger, oracle11gr2

I want to write the trigger that copies the old data into new table whenever the delete or update is happen.

So I have two tables **tableA** and **tableB**

**tableA** has following attributes: rollno, name, and status

**tableB** has following attributes: rollno, name

So, first whenever the delete operation is made on tableA I want to copy the old values to the tableB or second Whenever the value of the status attribute on tableA changes to specific value say 'C' then also I have to copy the old values.

I had written trigger that will copy the old values into tableB from tableA whenever delete or update is performed but the trigger is also executing for any update on the tableA.

Here is my trigger code

```
create or replace trigger my_trigger
before delete or update
on tableA
for each row
begin
    insert into tableB values(:OLD.rollno,:OLD.name);
end;
```

So how to execute trigger if the status attribute is updated?
I can check by using if statement in trigger that if the :NEW value is 'c' then execute the trigger but I also want to execute the trigger for delete statement also how can I do this?

I think I can use two triggers one for delete and one for update and inside update trigger i can check my condition but can I do this in one trigger only in oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, IF can help.

Here's an example based on Scott's schema; have a look.

This is a *log* table:

```
SQL> create table deptb as select * From dept where 1 = 2;

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bdu_dept
  2    before delete or update on dept
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if deleting then
  6      insert into deptb values (:old.deptno, :old.dname, :old.loc);
  7    elsif updating and :old.loc = 'NEW YORK' then
  8        insert into deptb values (:old.deptno, :old.dname, :old.loc);
  9    end if;
 10  end;
 11  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

SQL> delete from dept where deptno = 40;

1 row deleted.

SQL> update dept set loc = 'NY' where loc = 'NEW YORK';

1 row updated.

SQL> update dept set loc = 'dallas' where loc = 'DALLAS';

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from deptb;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK

SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NY
        20 RESEARCH             dallas
        30 SALES                CHICAGO

SQL>
```

Comment: I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as following:

```
create or replace trigger my_trigger
before delete or update of status
on tableA
for each row
WHEN (NEW.status= 'C' OR NEW.status IS NULL)
begin
   insert into tableB values(:OLD.rollno,:OLD.name);
end;
```

Only look for updates of column status with `update of status`. And then only execute the trigger when the new column value matches some condition `WHEN (NEW.status= 'C' OR NEW.status IS NULL)` checking for your value or null (in the delete case).

Comment: It is throwing me an error :
on tableA
*
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification